# Utility function must be continuous for $V(p, e(p,u) )$ to hold?

Tags: microeconomics, utility

Most utility functions we work with are already continuous, so I thought it was understood that it must continuous. But how would I show that if the utility function is discontinuous the identity V(p, e(p,u))=u might not hold?

Answer (score 1):

Define the function

$$
V(p, e(p, u)) - u = f(u) ~~~\mbox{for}~~~ u_\min \leq u \leq u_\max
$$

Your problem is then reduced to finding a point $u^* \in [u_\min, u_\max]$ such that $f(u^*)=0$. First, this problem may have not solution at all, even if the function is continuos. That being said, if the function is not continuos, you can have a situation like the one below
[image]

Clearly, this function is not continuos at $u=u_0$, moreover, it is not possible to find a point $u^*$ such that $f(u^*) = 0$.

Comment: In your answer the function $e(p,u)$ itself is not defined at $u^*$. As long as that is allowed there is no need to bother with such a complicated example. Let $e(p,u)$ be undefined everywhere. Now $V(p,e(p,u))$ is also undefined everywhere, hence $V(p,e(p,u)) \neq u$ for any $u$.

Comment: @denesp Why is $e(p,u)$ necessarily undefined and not $V(\cdot)$ alone?

Comment: @luchonacho What expenditure is requred to reach utility level $u$ at price $p$ if utility level $u$ can never be reached? (Because the utility function does not give value $u$ to anything.)

Comment: @denesp Elementary, my dear Watson...

Comment: @denesp My point is exactly that: if the function is not defined at a point, the problem $f(u) = 0$ may not have a solution. That's the reason for the graph, to show it more explicitly

Comment: But you are cheating with the definition. It is not that the function $V$ cannot take the value $u^*$ at $e(p,u^*)$, it is that the function $e(p,\cdot)$ is not defined at $u^*$. Again if this is allowed you can just say let the function $V$ be not defined anywhere. See, now it does not take any values.

Comment: (+1) Hard to know, perhaps this indeed what the OP wanted, but I feel like the more likely question is whether the equation holds if $e(p,u)$ is defined.